# Is there a noun or a noun phrase describing the "let stand" part in "Prepare the solution, let stand for 10 min"?

Tags: phrase-request, translation

I'm translating a table of deviations in a biotech manufacturing process. One of the sentences concerns an occurrence in which a solution was found not to conform to prescribed limits.

> Protein solution after **выдержки** failed to conform to the limits: the content of acidic forms exceeded 35%.

The Russian word means that the solution was simply doing nothing, sitting in a tube at room temperature. **Выдерживать** means "to keep" in Russian, and **выдержка** is "the process of keeping something".

After one of the manufacturing operations, the solution was left to stand for 10 minutes. As they usually write in English instructions: do this or that, swirl and **let stand for 10 minutes**. (In this particular table, I don't know how much time the solution actually spent "sitting", because the table contains occurrences recorded at different manufacturing sites on different days).

But how to express this in this sentence? Rummaging in my colleagues' Trados databases, I discovered that they translated similar phrases as **after keeping** and **after holding**, which does not look like idiomatic English to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of *stand*, consider using *rest*:

> The protein solution after **letting it rest** failed to conform to the limits: the content of acidic forms exceeded 35%.

It's used in the sense of

> 2 : to cease from action or motion : refrain from labor or exertion

<sub>(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rest#dictionary-entry-2))</sub>